# 5 star rating system mysql setup

Tags: php, mysql, rating-system

Ok so I know there's other questions like this. But mine is a little different...

I'm going to have a list with all the information of these games and i need to display the games average rating along with their info...

so, I dont want have 2 tables 'games' and 'games_ratings' because then i cant do a simple

```
SELECT id, name, howtoplay, otherinfo, avrating FROM games ORDER BY id;
```

it would be nice if there is a clever way I could have a 5 star rating system, that remembers users and can display an average value all in 1 table along with the information.

I dont know a lot about the limits of mysql. Should I just run 2 queries at once? Ive always tried to limit each page to only one query. especially if my first query will be loading 50 games to display info about.

im aware of the system where the ratings table is like userid, songid, rating and you just select the average.

Comment: With the system that you propose, how will you tell if a user has already rated a game?  Or how will they be able to change their rating?

Comment: well the one i said im aware of (that requires 2 tables) the users id is stored with their vote. but im asking if anyone knows more about mysql than me and can suggest a way of doing this in the other table. there probably isnt but figure id ask.

Comment: Try to refine your question a bit more.  I think you maybe don't quite have your end result clearly defined enough.  Take a look at the samples below and try them.  Let us know your problems from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb here as I think you may not only be new to mysql, but a bit new to modeling as well.

I would recommend 3 tables for this idea.

1. Users Table
2. UserRatings Table
3. Games Table

Users table is used to store just that.  User information.  Possibly a username, password, first name, last name for example.  The table should have a primary key.  Call it UsersID.  It should auto increment itself and be unique for every row.

The Games table is next.  Put a game name in it.  It should have a primary key as well.  Call it GameID.

Lastly is the UserRatings table.  I am a fan of primary keys over composite keys even in associative type tables, but you could go that route as well.  Say UserRatingsId, Rating, InsertTimeStamp, UpdateTimeStamp.

Now to store the average rating I would look at another table possibly, or putting a rating column inside the games table.  Every time you insert / update a row in the UserRatings table you fire off a refactor of that column, or table.

Also, joins are your friend.  Do a bit of reading on them.  Ignore outer, inner, cross, left, right etc until you are familiar with the concept of a simple straight join (and its called many things).

Try some of the answers provided above and this one.  I am guessing your questions will be much more targeted once you start playing around with it.

Cheers

Matt

Comment: Actually I won't recommend to store average rating as a separate field. OP will have to do a lot of work to ensure data consistency in that case - like adding multiple triggers on UserRatings insert/update/delete etc. All other points are useful, so +1

Comment: Yeah there are plenty of way to store it.  He doesn't indicate a need for anything more complex, but tons of great answers.  Thanks for the +1

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> it would be nice if there is a clever way I could have a 5 star rating system, that remembers users and can display an average value all in 1 table along with the information.

You must have a users table already. The only way to "remember" the user who has voted for a game is by a FK to the userID. Now, if you have one table mixing users and games then your table will lack normalization and will have the form:

```
+--------+----------------+------------------------+--------+------+
| GameId |    GameName    |    GameDescription     |  User  | Vote |
+--------+----------------+------------------------+--------+------+
|      1 | Counter Strike | An addicting FPS game! | Timmy  |    3 |
|      1 | Counter Strike | An addicting FPS game! | Martin |    5 |
|      1 | Counter Strike | An addicting FPS game! | Moe    |    2 |
|      2 | Halo           | Other addicting game   | Timmy  |    2 |
|      2 | Halo           | Other addicting game   | Sonny  |    2 |
+--------+----------------+------------------------+--------+------+
```

And this is not very normalized... Actually, you're gonna have GameDescription and GameName repeated everywhere! In this case, your PK will be GameId and User. You'll regret this sooner or later. So, lets not go for that. Go for this:

**Games** (PK: GameId)

```
+--------+----------------+------------------------+
| GameId |    GameName    |    GameDescription     |
+--------+----------------+------------------------+
|      1 | Counter Strike | An addicting FPS game! |
|      2 | Halo           | Other addicting game   |
+--------+----------------+------------------------+
```

**Users** (PK: User)

```
+--------+
|  User  |
+--------+
| Timmy  |
| Martin |
| Moe    |
+--------+
```

**Votes** (PK: GameId and User)

```
+--------+--------+------+
| GameId |  User  | Vote |
+--------+--------+------+
|      1 | Timmy  |    3 |
|      1 | Martin |    5 |
|      1 | Moe    |    2 |
|      2 | Timmy  |    2 |
|      2 | Sonny  |    2 |
+--------+--------+------+
```

Note: I'm assuming the username is the PK, you can use an integer userId too, but this was easier to read.

I know joins suck but they will help you more than they will hurt you.

Now, how can you improve the average calculation? Well, for each game you could have another column such as `TotalVotes` which will hold the total amount of votes and another column `SumVotes` which will hold the sum of all the votes for that game. So, when a vote is casted in increase by one the TotalVotes column and you add to SumVotes the amount of starts that the user assigned to the game.

Then, in order to display the average, just perform the division of both values (that's much faster than joining and scanning tables to recalculate this.

Well, I hope this helps or guide you to a better solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's no *efficient* way of storing this information in a single table. If you want it to be in one table just for query simplicity then I'd suggest using a view instead.

Let's imagine you have separate tables for games info and for ratings (yes, the approach you don't like :)). Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE games(id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255), howtoplay TEXT, otherinfo TEXT);

CREATE TABLE ratings(game_id INT, user_id INT, rating INT);
```

Then you can do the following:

```
CREATE VIEW games_with_ratings AS SELECT id, name, otherinfo, howtoplay, AVG(rating) AS avrating FROM games LEFT JOIN ratings ON games.id=ratings.game_id GROUP BY id;
```

You have to do it only once and after that you will be able to query this view just like you want in your original question:

```
SELECT id, name, howtoplay, otherinfo, avrating FROM games_with_ratings ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: I dont really know much about mysql. just basics, maybe a few functions, limits ect. im not sure what you mean by "view" would it be bad to run 2 select queries in my php function. is that normal? I dont really have a concept of what would be too much. ive just always tried to do 1 query at a time.

Comment: oohhh so a view is a way to query information from 2 tables at once...so i can just do 1 query like i said...?

Comment: Well, a view is a way to *represent* information - not necessarily from two tables. If you're OK with just doing JOIN (*this* is the simplest way to get information from several tables at once) then you can just write a query `SELECT id, name, otherinfo, howtoplay, AVG(rating) AS avrating FROM games LEFT JOIN ratings ON games.id=ratings.game_id GROUP BY id` and you'll get the same result. Just that approach with view will produce shorter queries as a result - but in both approaches this will be a single query.

Comment: You may want to read some documentation on JOIN: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29 (explains what it is and what it is for) and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html (explains MySQL-specific JOIN syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the average and total in the `games` table. When you add a new rating:

```
UPDATE games SET
    average=((average*totalvotes)+{$votescore})/(totalvotes+1),
    totalvotes=totalvotes+1
WHERE id={$id}
```

This is far more efficient than recalculating the average every time.

However, to remember who voted on what, the best way is a table with (`userid`, `gameid`, `score`) saved as an `InnoDB` table.

Comment: how would i get the information from my 'games_ratings' into a average column in my 'games' table? after I do an 'insert' on the 'games ratings' table...should have the mysql like return the new average then run an update on games?

Comment: You don't. You add the columns `average` and `totalvotes` to your `games` table, both defaulting to 0, and then let the code above do the work when it comes to making votes.